# Auto-renewable subscription rejected for confusing reasons: Any unused portion of a free trial period, if offered, will be forfeited

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

My app featuring an auto-renewable subscription was rejected for the following reason, which I find very confusing.

> Your app's binary did not include the following information about the
>   auto-renewable nature of the subscription:
>
> Any unused portion of a free trial period, if offered, will be
>   forfeited when the user purchases a subscription to that publication,
>   where applicable

This does not make any sense to me. As far as I know the free trail period will start at the moment the user purchases a subscription. It will not be forfeited at that time.

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could clarify this.

Comment: @Max, that's not a very helpful comment. Of course, I've contacted Apple. I've posted this question here while waiting for their response. By which I'm hoping to create a valuable reference for anyone that has this issue in the future.

Comment: And you answer yourself with that asking for more details was the way forward. Makes sense! I’m voting to close this topic as it’s opinion-based and hs nothing to do with programming

Comment: @Max, I respect that. Still I wish I had stumbled upon a question and answer like this myself. It would have saved me some time and worries and I hope this way it can guide the next person having an app rejected this way.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've got an answer from Apple. It solves my issue, but it's somewhat unsatisfying.

After my app was rejected for three reasons (among which the reason I described in my question) I replied by asking for a explanation.

Instead of responding with an explanation, my app is now rejected with just two reasons.

Comment: How do you solve "Any unused portion of a free trial period, if offered, will be forfeited when the user purchases a subscription to that publication, where applicable" Just got reject with this one and don't event know what should I do to solve this.

Comment: @sarunw, I assumed that this would be the case when you handle the user's trial period yourself (in the app or on your server). Then the free trial period would end when the user decides to make the in-app purchase. In my case however, the free trial period is handled by Apple *after* the user makes the in-app purchase. So I explained to Apple that this rule was not applicable to my app.